# Cypress login if not redirected to home page

Tags: reactjs, testing, cypress, e2e

I have a React app on http://localhost:3000/ which displays a login page, or if the user is logged in already then it will redirect to http://localhost:3000/home. This is the first time I'm trying Cypress and I'm not sure how to begin my test.

This is what I have so far:

```
describe("User can access home page after login", () => {
  it("displays home page", () => {
    cy.visit("http://localhost:3000/");
    cy.url().should("contain", "/home");
```

If the should() fails (so url does not contain "/home") then I want to fill in the login form with the username and password so I can access the rest of the app and run further tests. Is there a way to do some action only when the "should" function fails?

I tried without the should() to go straight to

```
cy.get('[type="text"]').type("email@email.com");
cy.get('[type="password"]').type("password");
```

but this gives an error if the user has already logged in because then there is no element in the page with the type="text".

**Edit:**

I've discovered cy.session but this gives the same error where the type="text" field doesn't exist because the page has already redirected. The cy.wait() doesn't seem to be helping.

```
describe("User can access home page after login", () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    cy.session("user", () => {
      cy.visit("http://localhost:3000/");
      cy.wait(5000);
      if (cy.url() !== "http://localhost:3000/home") {
        cy.get('[type="text"]').type("email@email.com");
        cy.get('[type="password"]').type("password");
        cy.get("section > :nth-child(3)").click();
        cy.wait(2000);
      }
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `.should()` is the wrong thing to use, because it fails the test if criteria isn't met.

But `.then()` can be used to check the url without failing

```js
describe("User can access home page after login", () => {
  it("displays home page", () => {
    cy.visit("http://localhost:3000/");
    cy.url().then(url => {
      if (!url.includes('/home') {
        // do your login here
      }
    })
```